# Unable to search managed properties for a document library

Tags: search, column, managed-metadata, managed-property

I have a document library with metadata that seems to have managed properties.  I want to be able to search these managed properties.  For example, I can do 'Filename:docx' and it shows only word docs.  But, when I do it with 'Title:safety' I get nothing.  Following this video https://youtu.be/plkHLLp1UjY, I went to the managed properties and got the property name and tried to search it as 'DOTTitleOWSTEXT:safety'.  Again, didn't work.  I ensured that the managed property is searchable.

Are there particular steps to make it work?  Let me know if additional info is needed.  Thanks everyone!